# Call a function in JavaScript by its name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying the next code without success

HTML

```
<a id="addBookButton" href="javascript:showForm('addBookButton','add-book','activateAddBookForm');" class="addA"><span>Add Book</span></a>

Javascript


function showForm(button,form,callback) {
    $("#"+button).hide();
        $("#"+form).show();
        callback();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just pass a reference to the function into your showForm function.

```
<a id="addBookButton" href="javascript:showForm('addBookButton','add-book',activateAddBookForm);" class="addA"><span>Add Book</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function showForm(button,form,callback) {
    $("#"+button).hide();
    $("#"+form).show();
    if (typeof this[callback] == "function") this[callback]();
}
```

Of you pass the function by value and not just the name of it:

```
<a id="addBookButton" href="javascript:showForm('addBookButton','add-book',activateAddBookForm);" class="addA"><span>Add Book</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your a tag to:

```
<a id="addBookButton" href="#" onclick="showForm('addBookButton','add-book','activateAddBookForm'); return false;" class="addA"><span>Add Book</span></a>
```

Note the `onclick` handler, and the `return false;` within the onclick.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showForm(button,form,callbackName) {
    $("#"+button).hide();
    $("#"+form).show();
    var callback = window.callbackName;
    if(typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="addBookButton" onclick="javascript:showForm('addBookButton','add-book','activateAddBookForm');" class="addA"><span>Add Book</span></a>
```

Javascript

```
function showForm(button,form,callback) {
  // Your Code
}

function callFunction(){
  document.getElementById('addBookButton').onclick();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One option is to pass the function be reference instead of as a string, so:

```
... javascript:showForm('addBookButton','add-book', activateAddBookForm); ....
```

or to continue using the string:

```
function showForm(button,form,callback) {
    $("#"+button).hide();
        $("#"+form).show();
        new Function(callback + '();')();
}
```